# How to split a string with a delimiter?

Tags: java

I have a string `"Foo*#*Bar*#*Foo1*#*Bar1"`

I want a regular expression which when used in `String.split(String RegularExpression)` will return

```
[0] = "Foo";
[1] = "Bar";
[2] = "Foo1";
[3] = "Bar1";
```

I tried `\*#*\`, but it not returning what i wanted.

Comment: What does 'Noob' stand for in this context?

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you want to split a string on `*#*`, or do you want to extract alphanumeric substrings? Or something else?

Comment: Hopefully the last edit sorted it out.

Comment: @downvoters: care to tell what's wrong?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal, the question has a Java tag, no need to mention it in the title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape both asterisks:

```
\*#\*
```

So in Java you'd do something like this:

```
String[] str = mystring.split("\\*#\\*");
```

Try [Regexr.com](http://regexr.com?31obo) for experimenting with regular expressions.

Comment: you mean `String[] str = mystring.split("\\*#\\*");`

Answer (score 3):

```
for (String part:"Foo*#*Bar*#*Foo1*#*Bar1".split("\\*#\\*"))
    System.out.println(part);
```

We need two backslashes on both stars (in java strings).

Answer (score 2):

For your example,

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

will return a list of all alphanumeric substrings in `subjectString`.

Alternatively, you can split on the delimiters:

```
String[] splitArray = subjectString.split("\\*#\\*");
```

Note that you have to double all the backslashes for use in a Java string.

Answer (score 1):

```
String splitable= "Foo*#*Bar*#*Foo1*#*Bar1";
String[] splitted=splitable.split("\\*#\\*");
```